# How do I fix Rigify Limbs in the horse rig?

Tags: rigging, rigify

I've generated a standard horse rig with Rigify and there is a moment I'd like to improve, but I can not understand how.
So on the front legs when I move the forefoot_ik I get the movement starts from the upper_arm. But I need it to start from the shoulder bone and I need to keep the position of the upper arm and shoulder as one solid structure (I'd like to have some option to switch between solid and free).
Here are examples. :

[Standard rig moves like this](https://i.gyazo.com/c29b730a93766c8538d1d8f4329f6b7a.mp4)

And

[I need to get this](https://i.gyazo.com/5fc160724590003275a314a0d91cb91f.mp4)

And here is some illustration of what joints I am talking about. The movement check on videos by the links.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you could do it but maybe you could find another way around, like creating 2 IKs, that would give you more control on the shoulder:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. But I don't quite get how the iks system will work in this case. Maybe you can help me with that.  From my post you see, that when I move the controller of the hoof the leg starts its movement from the upper arm, but does not affect the shoulder. If I change two bones with the one, then my IK will be influencing the shoulder, but I will lose the ability to control the upper arm only. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, after  I make it the part of IK it does influence all the shoulder. But there's no way to switch back to the upper-arm-only control. So every time I move the hoof my bone 1 is moving. But I need to be able to switch between moving all the shoulder vs moving only the upper arm by moving hoof control

Comment: but how the IK that has been deforming bone 1 will deform bone 3 without influencing bone 1?